# Mapping Refactoring with Expressions and linq select

Tags: lambda, linq-to-sql, refactoring, expression

My goal is to handle some mapping to DTOs in a *scaleable* way that cuts down on some of the boilerplate. I have to use Iqueryable here, and cannot just call .toList().

This piece works. (Also note, all properties of BusinessUnit are shown in the example, though i have about 25 more objects to map - some massive)

```
    //class BusinessUnitController
    private IQueryable<BusinessUnitDTO> BuildProjections()
    {

        IQueryable<BusinessUnitDTO> results = DataContext.BusinessUnits
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(BusinessUnitMapper.EntityToMessage);

        return results;
    }

    //Class businessUnitMapper
    public static Expression<Func<BusinessUnit, BusinessUnitDTO>> EntityToMessage = from => new BusinessUnitDTO
    {
        Id = from.Id,
        Name = from.Name,
        Code = from.Code
    };
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't really scale that great when i also need to be able to call it in other use cases. So I also have the following bits and pieces.

```
public BusinessUnitDTO Map(BusinessUnit from)
    {
        BusinessUnitDTO result = null;

        if (from != null)
        {
            result = new BusinessUnitDTO
            {
                Id = from.Id,
                Name = from.Name,
                Code = from.Code
            };
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and

```
     public static BusinessUnitDTO MapToMessage(this BusinessUnit businessUnit)
    {
        BusinessUnitMapper mapper = new BusinessUnitMapper();

        return mapper.Map(businessUnit);
    }
```

There has got to be a way to reuse this mapping in both cases. I tried to call the extension directly.. Example:

.Select(BusinessUnit.MapToMessage()); however, that doesnt work becuase it cannot convert that to SQL.

So how do i service both of those functional use cases while still only having to build the mapping out once? Is there any way i can use generics to vastly cut down on the boilerplate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile the mapper for client side use:

```
#class BusinessUnitMapper
public static Func<BusinessUnit, BusinessUnitDTO> BU2DTO = EntityToMessage.Compile();

public BusinessUnitDTO Map(BusinessUnit from)
    {
        BusinessUnitDTO result = null;

        if (from != null)
        {
            result = BU2DTO(from);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I couldn't resist a one-liner:

```
public BusinessUnitDTO Map(BusinessUnit from) => from != null ? BU2DTO(from) : default;
```